# Split string on whitespace ignoring parenthesis

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a string such as this

```
(ed) (Karlsruhe Univ. (TH) (Germany, F.R.))
```

I need to split it into two such as this

```
ed
Karlsruhe Univ. (TH) (Germany, F.R.)
```

Basically, ignoring whitespace and parenthesis within a parenthesis

Is it possible to use a regex to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can have more parentheses, it's better to use balancing groups:

```
string text = "(ed) (Karlsruhe Univ. (TH) (Germany, F.R.))";
var charSetOccurences = new Regex(@"\(((?:[^()]|(?<o>\()|(?<-o>\)))+(?(o)(?!)))\)");
var charSetMatches = charSetOccurences.Matches(text);
foreach (Match match in charSetMatches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/liZzjo)

Breakdown:

```
\((                     # First '(' and begin capture
    (?:                 
    [^()]               # Match all non-parens
    |
    (?<o> \( )          # Match '(', and capture into 'o'
    |
    (?<-o> \) )         # Match ')', and delete the 'o' capture
    )+
    (?(o)(?!))          # Fails if 'o' stack isn't empty

)\)                     # Close capture and last opening brace
```

Comment: Thanks! It works as expected. Yes, you are right. There could be any number of parenthesis groups.

Answer (score 0):

```
\((.*?)\)\s*\((.*)\)
```

you will get the two values in two match groups \1 and \2

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/rP5kG2

and [**this**](http://regex101.com/r/eB2eV3) is what you get if you search and replace with the pattern `\1\n\2` which also seems to be what you need exactly

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = "(ed) (Karlsruhe Univ. (TH) (Germany, F.R.))";
Regex re = new Regex(@"\((.*?)\)\s*\((.*)\)");

Match match = re.Match(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, No.
You can't describe recursive patterns in regular expression. ( Since it's not possible to recognize it with a finite automaton. )