# Regex get text between parentheses and keywords

Tags: regex, text, keyword, parentheses

i have a text pattern like this;

```
(((a) or (b) or (c)) and ((d) or (e)) and ((!f) or (!g)))
```

and i want to get it like this;

```
((a) or (b) or (c))
((d) or (e))
((!f) or (!g))
```

After that i want to seperate them like this;

```
a,b,c
d,e
!f,!g
```

any help would be awesome :)

**edit 1:** sorry about the missing parts; using language is C# and this is what i got;

```
(\([^\(\)]+\))|([^\(\)]+)
```

with i got;

```
(a) or (b) or (c) and (d) or (e) and (!f) or (!g)
```

thanks already!

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you. Show us the actual code that you've tried, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Comment: sorry about the missings :)

Comment: I think it might be easier to do this without regex

Comment: Nested elements and RegEx, oh my.

Comment: tried somethings but seems like its kind a hard to deal with these nested things. with my pattern i got what i need after that i'll try to split them with character control :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking [this previous regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22496788/1578604) and modifying the code a little...

```
string msg= "(((a) or (b) or (c)) and ((d) or (e)) and ((!f) or (!g)))";
var charSetOccurences = new Regex(@"\(((?:[^()]|(?<o>\()|(?<-o>\)))+(?(o)(?!)))\)");
var charSetMatches = charSetOccurences.Matches(msg);
foreach (Match mainMatch in charSetMatches)
{
    var sets = charSetOccurences.Matches(mainMatch.Groups[1].Value);
    foreach (Match match in sets)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[0].Value);
    }
}
```

The first regex is being used to get the contents of the outermost paren.

The same regex is then used to get the individual sets within the 'larger' content. You get this as output:

```
((a) or (b) or (c))
((d) or (e))
((!f) or (!g))
```

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/rkUDPq)

If you want to remove the outer parens, just change the innermost line:

```
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[0].Value);
```

to

```
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
```

To get:

```
(a) or (b) or (c)
(d) or (e)
(!f) or (!g)
```

I trust you can take it from here.

Comment: Thanks man! i just saw your answer and this will work too! I'll update my question with my answer too :)

Answer (score 0):

After my work i figure this;

```
  string msg = "(((a) or (b) or (c)) and ((d) or (e)) and ((!f) or (!g)))";

  Regex regex = null;
  MatchCollection matchCollection = null;

  regex = new Regex(@"(\([^\(\)]+\))|([^\(\)]+)"); // For outer parantheses
  matchCollection = regex.Matches(query);
  foreach (Match match in matchCollection)
  {
    MatchCollection subMatchCollection = Regex.Matches(match.Value, @"(""[^""]+"")|([^\s\(\)]+)"); // For value of inner parantheses
    foreach (Match subMatch in subMatchCollection)
    {
      //with 2 loops i got each elements of this type of string.
    }
  }
```

Thanks to everyone! :)